# How do I Install Drupal 7 on a remote server?

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

I have my Drupal 7 website on a wamp server in localhost ready to be uploaded to the remote server.

The remote server does not have Drupal 7 installed.

How do I install Drupal 7 in the remote server, keeping all the same settings, modules, themes and databases that are in localhost?

Thanks for the very helpful answers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Drupal.org has an entire page devoted to this question:

http://drupal.org/upgrade/copying-your-test-site-via-GUI

Answer (score 1):

I suggest taking a look at Aegir. Aegir is a Drupal-based deployment package.

It allows you to clone your Drupal sites, keep them up-to-date, and perform a variety of other management tasks.

http://www.aegirproject.org/